# Is this argument valid for a proof?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Please kindly forgive me if my question is too naive, i'm just a *prospective* undergraduate who is simply and deeply fascinated by the world of numbers.

My question is: Suppose we want to prove that $f(x) > \frac{1}{a}$, and we *know* that $g(x) > a$, where $f,g$ and $a$ are all positive and $a$ is a nonzero real number.
                                                                                  *If we can show* that $f(x)g(x) > 1$, would that imply our required proof ?

EDIT: As demonstrated by various users in the solutions below, the answer is definitely *no*. 
                                                                              What about if we now want to prove the *reverse* inequality $f(x) \leq \frac{1}{a}$ given that $g(x) < a$, if we can show that $f(x)g(x)<1$, i guess our required result would follow ?

Comment: You need to make some assumption about positivity.  If, say, $a=-2$ and $g(x)=-1$ then we have $g(x)>a$.  But then, if $f(x)=-10$ it is true that $f(x)g(x)>1$ but it is not true that $f(x)>-\frac 12$

Comment: @Lulu, yes, consider $f,g$ and $a$ to be all positive. Let me add that in the edit , thanks !

Comment: Sorry, it still isn't true (I read it too quickly before).  Take $a=1$, $g(x)=10$, $f(x)=\frac 12$

Comment: It'd be true if you knew that g(x) was *LESS* than a.

Comment: Okay, thank you all. Please do kindly reconsider the question in the present form.

Comment: You know if $fg ?? 1$ then $f ?? 1/g$ and you know that if $g ?? a$ then the *OPPOSITE*  $1/a ?? 1/g$.  So if $fg ?? 1$ and $a ?? g$ you can conclude $f ?? 1/a$. However if $g ?? a$,  you can not conclude anything.  It's the same as if these were constants.

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing boils done to:

if $a > b$ (a and b positive) then $1/a < 1/b$.  The reciprical "*flips*" the inequality.

$f(x)g(x) < 1$ (or greater than) implies $f(x) < 1/g(x)$ (or greater than).  To get a result $g(x) ?? a$ must be the *OPPOSITE* inequality because $1/g(x)$ and $1/a$ will be "flipped".

So if $f(x)g(x) < 1$ and $g(x) > a$ (!!!!!!**GREATER**!!!!!!!!) then you can conclude $f(x) < 1/a$.

And if $f(x)g(x) > 1$ and $g(x) < a$ (!!!!!!!**LESS THAN**!!!!!!!) then you can conclude $f(x) > 1/a$.

But if $f(x)g(x) > 1$ and $g(x) > a$ or if $f(x)g(x) < 1$ and $g(x) < a$ you can not conclude a g**d****ed thing.

==============

No.  If $g(x)$ is *LESS* than $a$ but more than zero, you may conclude $f(x)g(x) > 1$ so $f(x) > 1/g(x) > 1/a.$

But if $g(x) > a$.  We have $f(x)g(x) > 1 \implies f(x) > 1/g(x)$ and $1/g(x) < f(x)$ but we cant conclude anything.  (Or we have $f(x)g(x) > f(x)a$ and $f(x)g(x) > 1$ but we don't have $f(x)a > 1$.)

A counter is $a = 1; g(x) = 4$ (a constant function) and $f(x) = 1/2$  $f(x) < 1/a$ while $f(x)g(x) = 2 > 1$ and $g(x) > a$.

===

Again no.  If $f(x), g(x), a > 0$ then $f(x)g(x) >|=|< 1$ then $f(x) >|=|< 1/g(x)$  If we know $g(x) >|=|< a$ then $1/g(x) <|=|> 1/a$.

Given this we have nine possible situations:

1) $f(x)g(x) < 1; g(x) < a$.  Then $f(x) < 1/g(x) > 1/a$.  No conclusions.

2) $f(x)g(x) = 1; g(x) < a$.  Then $f(x) = 1/g(x) > 1/a$.  Conclusion: $f(x) > 1/a$.

3) $f(x)g(x) > 1; g(x) < a$ Then $f(x) > 1/g(x) > 1/a$.  Conclusion: $f(x) > 1/a$

4) $f(x)g(x) < 1; g(x) = a$.  Then $f(x) < 1/g(x) = 1/a$.  Conclusion: $f(x) < 1/a$

5) $f(x)g(x) = 1; g(x) = a$.  Then $f(x) = 1/g(x) = 1/a$.  Conclusion: $f(x) = 1/a$.

6) $f(x)g(x) > 1; g(x) = a$ Then $f(x) > 1/g(x) = 1/a$.  Conclusion: $f(x) > 1/a$

7) $f(x)g(x) < 1; g(x) > a$.  Then $f(x) < 1/g(x) < 1/a$.  Conclusion: $f(x) < 1/a$

8) $f(x)g(x) = 1; g(x) > a$.  Then $f(x) = 1/g(x) < 1/a$.  Conclusion: $f(x) < 1/a$.

9) $f(x)g(x) > 1; g(x) > a$ Then $f(x) > 1/g(x) < 1/a$.  No conclusion.

Comment: okay thanks. Please kindly reconsider the question in its present form.

Answer (score 0):

No, it wouldn't imply that. Because, if $g(x)>a$ , Let's take $g(x) = na ; n>1$
$f(x)g(x)=naf(x)$ 
 If you prove $f(x)g(x)>1$ , You get $naf(x) > 1$ $\implies$ $f(x) > $$1\over na$ ; $n>1$ Which is not what you wanted. 
 $f(x)$ can lie between $1\over na$ and $1\over a$ !!

Answer (score 0):

No, you could have $g$ huge and $f$ tiny. Let $a=10, g=1000, f=1/50$

Answer (score 0):

Unless i'm missing something horribly wrong, it seems the *current* form of the question is straightforward (though this appears to contradict with fleablood's answer):

We know that $g(x)<a$,  let $f(x)\leq t$. Therefore $f(x)g(x)<at$. But we also know that $f(x)g(x)<1$, hence we should have $t \leq \frac{1}{a}$, which yields $f(x)\leq t \leq \frac{1}{a}$, as required.